# win < docker < nginx ipconfig

Tags: nginx, docker, windows-7, docker-machine

just for better understanding:

I have a windows7 machine/virtualBox. The  Docker machine is runing an I deployed a nginx container to it. So far so good.

Now I just wonder...

In all documentations stands that I just have to use:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginxImg
```

And then I can reach the engine with

localhost:8080

But in my env my localhost cant reach the container.
I have to use the "docker-machin ip".
e.g.

192.168.99.100:8080 
and that reaches the nginx Container.

Its ok for me, but I want to know why it works diffrent on my machine then in all docs explained?? Did I miss something or made a mistake?

Kind regards
Gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they say localhost it means that the host machine where the docker server is running. This in your case is the Virtual Machine. Which has an IP `192.168.99.100`.

If this VM has GUI installed and you can launch a browser inside the VM then you will be able to browse `localhost:8080` inside the VM.

But from your Windows machine the VM is as good as a remote server. So you need the IP to reach it.

Comment: Thanks :) Iam just that I didnt miss something.